# m_BoneMapping is undefined in OpenGL Step By Step Skeletal Animation Tutorial

Tags: opengl, animation, skeletal-animation, assimp

I am new to this [website](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) I was following this specific [tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) on skeletal animation and I have a good idea on what it is, but when I was following his implementation he used a variable called "m_BoneMapping" and which is undefined to me. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging tutorial code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that tutorial doesn't include all of the source code but I did find a link to it on the main page, here: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/

The Mesh class appears to have an m_BoneMapping member, which the tutorial describes as the following:

> The m_BoneMapping array maps a node name to the index that we generate
>   and we use that index to as an entry into the m_BoneInfo array where
>   the final transformations are stored.

The tutorial describes the m_BoneMapping as an array, but the source code suggests otherwise. It appears to be a `std::map<std::string, unsigned>` which maps a name (string) to an index (unsigned).

It is populated in the `void Mesh::LoadBones(uint MeshIndex, const aiMesh* pMesh, vector& Bones)` method, and used in `void Mesh::ReadNodeHeirarchy(float AnimationTime, const aiNode* pNode, const Matrix4f& ParentTransform)`

If you add that to your Mesh class it looks like it should all work out.